How to Remove Extra White Background from BottomNavigationView in Android?
I am currently working on an Android project where I have implemented a BottomNavigationView within a BottomAppBar. However, I am encountering an issue where there is an extra white background around the icon labels in the BottomNavigationView, which I am unable to remove.

My xml layout :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lt_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


Output Image :


You can customize the appearance of the labels by modifying the BottomNavigationView's item text color and background in style
 <!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<resources>
<style name="BottomNavigationViewLabelStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_desired_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

Next, apply this custom style to the BottomNavigationView in your layout XML file.
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewLabelStyle"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewLabelStyle" />

Ensure that your app theme is not overriding these styles. You can define these attributes in your app's theme if necessary.
<!-- res/values/themes.xml -->
<resources>
<style name="Theme.YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/BottomNavigationViewLabelStyle</item>
</style>

